# Django version 2.1 Django-admin.py startproject only creates manage.py

Tags: python, django, anaconda, virtualenv

I'm using anaconda on Windows 10 with python version 3.6.5. These are the commands that I ran on Django 2.1.0:

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper.win
mkvirtualenv firstBlog
workon firstBlog
pip install Django
Django-admin.py startproject firstBlog
cd firstBlog
dir
```

and this is the output I get:

```
08/22/2018  02:48 PM    <DIR>          .
08/22/2018  02:48 PM    <DIR>          ..
08/22/2018  02:48 PM    <DIR>          firstBlog
08/22/2018  02:48 PM               556 manage.py
               1 File(s)            556 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  137,288,876,032 bytes free
```

Why did startproject not make init.py, urls.py and settings.py?

I should add that I'm trying to make a website that someone can draw numbers with their mouse onto a 28x28 grid and then have a neural network recognize the number they drew on the website. It's a passion project of mine.

Comment: For that you should create an app inside the project.

Comment: Your project urls.py and settings.py should be inside the firstBlog directory, is it not?

Comment: As an aside, re: the neural network; have you looked at the MNIST database? Good for training your network. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MNIST_database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, you need to point it at the file path of `django-admin.py` directly. For example:
`C:\Users\filip\Python\ENV\Scripts\django-admin.py`

After that, you've started a *project*, which can have any number of apps.

You next need to create an app:

`manage.py startapp my-app-name`

This will create the project directory structure.

Have a look at the docs here [manage and django-admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/)